# Usage of the dot '.' symbol in twitter hashtags

Tags: .net, twitter, hashtag

In the official [Twitter FAQ](https://support.twitter.com/articles/49309-what-are-hashtags-symbols) about hashtags, it is unclear how the dot '.' symbol can be used.

A simple comparison: #.net VS #dotnet (I mean Microsoft .NET Framework here).

It seems that the first hashtag gains more search results by the most of the hashtags analyzer sites. However, the official Twitter.com does not highlight hashtags containing the dot as links, so you can't click it and search for similar tweets.

I wonder is it good idea to use the dot '.' character in hashtags of a tweet for a better understanding and also shorten its overall length by 2 characters ("." VS "dot")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the hashtags with a dot don't show up in search, it stands to reason that those hashtags would not be effective in the current system.

This blog entry indicates some of what you can and cannot (or should not) do: http://andrewtaylr.tumblr.com/post/1448457139/five-ways-you-are-doing-twitter-wrong